# Creating a continuous raster road network using Polygon to Raster in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: raster, polygon, arcgis-pro, network, road

I have a polygon forest road network that I would like to turn into a raster. I have attempted to use the ArcGIS [Polygon to Raster tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/polygon-to-raster.htm), but whenever the majority of a cell falls outside of the polygon, it is given a value of No Data, meaning that the resulting raster does not have continuous roads. See image below, with black outlines representing the vector features.

[image: Black outlines represent vector features, purple and green cells are the raster output, Value = OBJECTID]

I have tried setting a priority field, changing the cell assignment method, and buffering the roads (this works but produces inaccurate results). The only solution I have found so far is to calculate the center lines of the roads and then use the [Polyline to Raster tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/polyline-to-raster.htm) to create the road network. This works (see below), though it adds complexity to the workflow.

[image: Orange lines are center lines of black-outlined vector features. Raster Value = OBJECTID]

Does anyone know of a method of creating continuous road networks from polygons, without needing to calculate the center lines?

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.2.3.

I have attempted to use a finer cell size (1m) and then [re-sample](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/resample.htm) back to the original cell size (10m). Unfortunately, while the output is better, the original problem persists (see below).

[image: Left image is 1m Raster, right image shows raster after resampling to 10 meter resolution.]

Comment: Can you make your output raster grid a *lot* finer? Much smaller grid cells should be in the road polygons.

Comment: I'll try, though I'm already using a 10m raster, with a substantial study area (processing time is starting to be an issue).

Comment: You have already found the best solution by adding the polyline to raster step.  One extra step is not a lot of complexity.  Much less complex than the re-sampling process.  The polygon problem will persist due to the cell size being wider than the roads.